# Допустим есть динамический массив. В этот динамический массив должен добавляться элемент и индекс, который вводит пользователь. Как это реализуется?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RandArr (int* arr, const int size);
void PrintArr(int* arr, const int size);
int* AddArr(int* arr, int size, int* new_size, int indx, int el);





int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
; 
    int size, el, indx;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int* arr = new int[size];
    RandArr(arr, size);
    PrintArr(arr, size);
    cout << "Веведите индекс массива: ";
    cin >> indx;
    cout << "Введите эллемент массива: ";
    cin >> el;

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}

void RandArr(int* arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void PrintArr(int* arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну, а вы как думаете? Как пробовали это сделать?...

Comment: Объясните, как работать с добавлением, если это не начало и не конец массива.

Comment: "Раздвиганием" массива. Перемещением элементов...

Comment: я думаю, что нужно создать новый массив с размером больше предыдущего. Но суть в том, что я понимаю, что он будет больше за счет введных пользователем данных. но не могу понять, как их добавить именно в то место, куда решил пользователь.

Comment: Нарисуйте картинку. При размещении нового элемента в какое-то k-е место, все, что слева, будет на месте, все что справа - сместится. Нужный элемент станет в k-е место. Всё. Создавайте новый массив с б*о*льшим размеров и перекопируйте в него элементы так, как на рисунке...